# Symfony4 - how to deal with functionality

Tags: symfony, structure, bundles

I'm new to Symfony4 and I want your advices guys to help me on this. 
Let's say I want to create a page like facebook, with posts, comments, like action on the same page. I'm wondering how I should do to be able to enable/disable a functionality quickly and also split my code in order to have light and readable files.

Comment: integrate some bundle to your application and start using facebook api https://packagist.org/packages/hwi/oauth-bundle,  https://developers.facebook.com/

Answer (score 0):

Reading this can't hurt:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html

Your question is too vague, there's no magic answer to "How to do a good Symfony App".
Symfony is a framework with a pretty hard learning curve. You need to get a good grasp on it's bases, practice and take a look on how other Symfony applications are written, or even better find someone to review your architecture and give you pointers.